# Is there a way for a closed domain chatbot to build using seq2seq, generative modeling or other methods like RNNs?

Tags: machine-learning, chatbot, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq, blenderbot

Let's say I have a closed-domain chatbot, and it's knowledge base is in Finance. Thus, of course I want the chatbot to answer questions that the user might have like, "How is the best way to save money?", or "What are my spending habits like the past 3 months?". However, I would also want the chatbot to be able to remember the conversation (up to a certain date) as well as model what generative models like [BlenderBot](https://ai.facebook.com/blog/state-of-the-art-open-source-chatbot/) (Facebook AI Research) or [Meena](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/01/towards-conversational-agent-that-can.html) (Google AI) are able to do. The ability to respond to anyway the conversation flows?

Is it a question of just building out my intents to classify? Or should I be looking to involve both intent classification and seq2seq modeling? If so, how would one do that? Any blogs, tutorials would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this? I am too looking for a solution where we can train a model on some custom data and then getting answer from that trained model